# Strange route line in OpenVPn status log

Tags: networking, routing, openvpn

I have a program that parses a openvpn-status.log file in order to give me the data in a WebApp.

Today I found a strange network notation in one on my openvpn client connections. I've been digging out, and I found that the source is in my server's openvpn-status.log file.

As expected, it shows the PROPER route line (public IP and cert name changed to random for privacy. (Originally both had the same public IP, though)

```
ROUTING_TABLE,172.16.10.0/24,cl833,45.124.41.35:42623,Tue Dec 22 08:38:17 2020,1608622697
```

But also shows this ODD line:

```
ROUTING_TABLE,172.16.10.5C,cl833,45.124.41.35:42623,Tue Dec 22 19:37:06 2020,1608662226
```

What does the 172.16.10.5C stands for? It is some kind of notation I don't know? Is it a glitch in openvpn-status.log? I thought the C may stand for C class network, but the 5 is a total mistery to me.

My father has seen this several days. It fixes itself and appears again after a few days.

**The ccd file is properly configured, and the client.conf has nothing special.**

PD: Everything works just fine, even when this shows up, but this is puzzling me. I can't reproduce the issue. I managed to save the file when I detected it, but for now it is gone. I can just check if the network is well formed and filter it out while processing the file, but I'd like to know where does it come from.

Comment: I wonder if this is a typo in the server config - pushing a route with a typo?   If you list the routing table does it show any routes which can't be explained except by this?

Comment: @davidgo I'll check linux route table next time it happens to see if it gets populated, although the client device is using ospf to populate routes to the main network, and I think that it would fail if such a route is passed, so my hunch is that it is restricted to openvpn internal route table.

The route is not present in any ospf file or any other config in the client device or in the server. I don't know where that C may come from :S. Also there's a 11 hour difference between the route creations

Comment: Another extreme long shot, but it might be worth looking for 172.16.10.92 as well - 5C HEX being 92 decimal.